# grant permission to execute .c file

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, exec

i created a file by the following code

```
$dir = '/home/srikanth/Desktop';
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
  mkdir ($dir, 0777);
 }
//$code contains the code C code which i want to execute
 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.c', $code);
$path = "/home/srikanth/Desktop/test.c";
$Command = "gcc $path 2&>1";
exec($Command,$return_val,$error);
```

when i open my error log file 
 i see the following error

```
sh: 1: cannot create 1: Permission denied
gcc: error: 2: No such file or directory
```

i tried the following commands to change the permission ,I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.2 and Apache server

```
chmod 0777 /home/srikanth/Desktop/test.c
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/srikanth/Desktop/test.c




sudo usermod -aG www-data root
addgroup www-data
```

I used these commands to add www-data to root group
but i still keep on getting the same file in my error log

Comment: from the `cannot create .. Permission denied` it's quite possible that the errors are because the php/apache user doesn't have permissions to create files in that directory, meaning the output of `gcc`. verify this with `su "phpuser"; touch php-file.txt` and the same for apache

Comment: place the test.c file in your project and run the php file once because sometimes it cannot access other files rather than www folder

Comment: thanks @Tamil Selvan but i get "Failed to create /var/www/html/test.c"
/var/www/html is the directory where i have placed my php files
and moreover when i tried to change permissions for the path /var/www/html i get 
"chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var’: Operation not permitted"

Comment: i have provided the permissions for my file as mentioned abve @AlexAndrei

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this issue is a permissions issue, in so much as the server user can not create folders/files in the /home/srinkanth/Desktop directory. Or something in the gcc compiler can not create files during compilation of your c code.

Adding 777 to that DIRECTORY (not the test file on its own) will likely fix the problem. However, good practice is to add exits/exceptions in your code to give you more visibility on problems if and when they happen and what caused them.

Here is my advice:

```
$dir = '/home/srikanth/Desktop';
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    $mkDir = mkdir($dir, 0777);
    if (!$mkDir) {
        exit('Failed to create ' . $dir);
    }
}
```

Then you can add additional de-bugging info to your put file code:

```
$codePath = $dir.'/test.c';
$created = file_put_contents($codePath, $code);
if (!$created) {
    exit('Failed to create ' . $codePath);
}
```

The if you reach this stage more to your execute file code:

```
$codePath = $dir . '/test.c';
$command = "gcc $codePath 2&>1";

$output = [];
$returnStatus = '';
$lastLine = exec($command, $output, $returnStatus);
```

Then you can output your whole gcc compile by glueing the output array pieces back together with a new line as exec parses each line of output as a record in the output array:

```
echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Hope this helps.
Goodluck.

Comment: thanks @DanBelden 
but i get the following error
"
sh: 1: cannot create 1: Permission denied
gcc: error: 2: No such file or directory"

Comment: Is that the final output of the code you are running? gcc seems to indicate the file does not exist? Can you confirm test.c was created and contains the code you need it too? That way you can see where in your code is failing without the error.

Comment: thanks @ danbelden 
using my terminal i tried to run the code and its working fine
test.c was created in the given path and it contains the code

Comment: In which case it's 100% a permission problem try making a new directory, for example /home/srikanth/test and making the permissions 777 (chmod 777 /home/srikanth/test) then modifying your code to match the new directory path and running it. See what the problem is then. Running exec from PHP starts to involve the PHP user, path and many other variables which can work strangely to your bash variables. Goodluck!